# SonarQube java heap OutOfMemory

Tags: java, continuous-integration, sonarqube, out-of-memory, devops

I am runnig sonarQube from docker compose.
I am getting java heap OutOfMemory exception. How can I adjust configuration or env variables to be able to process big project ??

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEtUu.png)

I am trying to specify these
SONAR_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx5g -Xms2g"
SONAR_CE_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx5g -Xms2g"
,but when I check docker log I cannot see the right settings

`sonarqube-sonarqube-1  | 2023.09.13 09:02:18 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[COMPUTE_ENGINE] from [/opt/sonarqube]: /opt/java/openjdk/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube/temp -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED -Dcom.redhat.fips=false -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.*|[::1] -cp ./lib/sonar-application-10.1.0.73491.jar:/opt/sonarqube/lib/jdbc/postgresql/postgresql-42.6.0.jar org.sonar.ce.app.CeServer /opt/sonarqube/temp/sq-process15823221518521224531properties`

```
version: "3"

services:
  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube:community
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      SONAR_JDBC_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonar
      SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME: sonar
      SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD: sonar
      SONAR_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx5g -Xms2g"
      SONAR_CE_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx5g -Xms2g"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data
      - sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
      - sonarqube_logs:/opt/sonarqube/logs
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
  db:
    image: postgres:12
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: sonar
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: sonar
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
      - postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  sonarqube_data:
  sonarqube_extensions:
  sonarqube_logs:
  postgresql:
  postgresql_data:
```

I need to set 5g to compute engine to be able to process the analysis on sonars side